# How to allow Contributor users to mark discussion board items as Featured

Tags: 2013, permissions, administration, discussion-board, custom-permission-level

I am working on a Discussion Board list inside sharepoint on-premises 2013. and i added a discussion board list inside my team site. where this team site have the publishing features enabled. 
But i am not sure why contributor users who can add, edit,delete discussion board items can not mark a discussion board item as featured?

[image]

now the user need full control on the list to be able to do this. but my question is what is the minimum permission which i need to grant for a contributor user to be able to mark a discussion board list item as featured?
Thanks

now i try this appraoch for testing purposes only. where i modify the built-in Contribute permission, and i add the following permission to it "override list behavior" :-

[image]

where this allowed contributor users to mark the items as featured. but this create another problem, is that users can now edit and delete items they did not create, which will be against what we have set insie the list advance settings!! and this will apply to all the list on the site. so i remove the permission from the contribute build-in permission level. so could this help in identifying how to have a custom permission level which can allow contributor users to mark discussion board items as featured, without having any extra permission on the lists and items?